# Statistics about the frequency of different type of intervals

Tags: theory, intervals

Do you know if any statistics about the frequency of different type of intervals in music (of a certain period or by a specific composer) exist?

For instance, suppose you have this piece of music in c major:
(c' is c upper octave)

c d e g c' g c'

Then we have these intervals:

c d
d e
e g
g c'
c' g
g c'

The interval that occurs more frequently is g c'.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome, G. Lari. Have you tried Google Scholar?

Comment: I'm interested in what you will do with any data that is forthcoming.

Comment: Ciao Tim, it was mainly a curiosity. But at the beginning the idea was didactical. When you learn a language, you start from simple things and very frequent words. I was wondering if it was possible to do something similar with music: writing simple musical piece starting with the more frequent intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recent study that I haven't had a chance to check out yet can be found [here](https://osf.io/rkptu/). In the abstract the authors say that they "statistically quantify note usage with respect to pitch class and intervals," and they go on to say that "[i]nterval usage predicts individual composer identity at levels above chance."

And if you're interested in doing this type of work yourself, definitely check out [music21](https://web.mit.edu/music21/); such a study would be very easy to do with this framework.

Comment: Fascinating stuff.  But you have to wonder what sort of protocols they use to count intervals.  Do, say, melodies doubled at the octave count as octaves?